# Accessing Fields , Java

Tags: java, visibility

i have a problem at accessing certain fields in my code and i would like to know an efficient way to deal with this.

```
public class Indexer {
static private int startKeyIndex = 0;
    static private String patternKey = new String();
                    .
                    .
private static void extractIndexes(String content) throws IOException {
    patternKey = "this is a regex for finding keywords,  hi!"
    startKeyIndex = extractIndexFromPattern(contentKey, patternKey);
}                   .
                    .
                    .
private static void extractKeywords(String pattern, String content) throws IOException{   
    //The problem is in this method
    CharSequence contentSeq = content.subSequence(0,3000);
    String area = extractStringFromPattern(content, patternKey);    
}
```

Comment: How you are accessing ?

Comment: what are the certain fields?

Comment: @ What do you mean by "cant access the value of startKeyIndex ". Is it giving you compilation error?

Comment: What ecactly doesn't work? `Indexer.startKeyIndex`

Comment: You should have access to `startKeyIndex` from `extractKeywords`, can you post more code?

Comment: Is the method `extractKeyWords` in the same class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything working fine.And you can access those filed and field value too.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
static private int startKeyIndex = 0;


private static void extractIndexes(String content) throws IOException {
    startKeyIndex = 10;
    System.out.println(startKeyIndex);
}                   


private static void extractKeywords(String pattern, String content) throws 
                                                                IOException{   
    System.out.println(startKeyIndex);
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    extractIndexes("");
    extractKeywords("", "");
}


}
```

**And Result is :**

```
10
10
```